# Why is Firefox not accepting bottom % padding values?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, flexbox

I have problems with inconsistent looks between Chrome and Firefox. To my surprise, even after using reset.css I still have the same problems; it's like Firefox is not using any of the padding that are set in "%", if I set the padding in pixels then it does work.

W3 validator came out clean.

My problem:

[image]

Right side is Firefox, and that's after using reset.

This is the style of the div:

```css
.hobbies {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5% 10% 15% 10%;
  background: #66B9BF;
  color: #373737;
}
```

In Chrome, the padding is what stretches the div, but that's not happening in Firefox.

```css
.me-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 3%;
    background: #373737;
} 
.hobby-title {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.hobbies {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5% 10% 15% 10%;
    background: #66B9BF;
}
.hobbies-icons{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.icon {
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #373737;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.icon-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: initial;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="me-wrap">   
    <div class="hobbies">
        <h1 class="hobby-title"> Hobbies/Interests </h1>
        <div class="hobbies-icons">
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Animal lover </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Code enthusiast </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Exercise practicioner </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Videogame aficionado </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Geek culture adherent </p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="icon-text"> Outdoor nut </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a basic example in jsfiddle or similar, displaying the issue? You may have conflicting styles elsewhere.

Comment: I'm afraid the code is too large, I guess I was looking to know if this was a known issue caused by X.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] of this. At the very least we need to see the HTML of the affected element and its parent, as well as any CSS for the element and its parent that affects layout.

Comment: Added some of the code.

Comment: A few things: 1) you might want to recheck your W3 validation; you can't put divs in p tags. 2) The behavior is identical on FF and Chrome insofar as left- and right-padding are concerned, so I clarified in your question about bottom padding, which is the only difference. 3) This is a good complete and verifiable demo, but it's not minimal. Try to reduce the code to just the parts needed to reproduce the behavior of the icons with the padding problem.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue that could be resolved by using an `overflow: hidden;` on the container that has the blue background and the fat grey border. Rather than being an issue with the `hobbies` class itself, it appears to be a problem with one of the parent containers. As one of the other commenters said, please post a bit more code and we can probably help out more.